# UIScrollView not working in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I have made a baseViewController which is derived from UIViewController, SlideMenuDelegate and UIWebViewDelegate
Then I have created subclass which are derived from baseviewcontroller

1. LoginVC - displays login screen
2. PlayVC - shows a webview if login is successful.

Everything is fine except that webview is not scrolling at all.

I have tried everything suggested in all posts so far regarding scrolling
Below is my code written in PlayVC.swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var web1: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addSlideMenuButton()


    let webUrl : URL = URL(string: "http://brainyknights.com")!
    let webRequest : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: webUrl)

    web1.scalesPageToFit = true
    web1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    web1.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    web1.loadRequest(webRequest)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: remove this line `web1.scalesPageToFit = true`

Answer (score 4):

remove this line `web1.scalesPageToFit = true`

```
@IBOutlet weak var web1: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSlideMenuButton()


        let webUrl : URL = URL(string: "http://brainyknights.com")!
        let webRequest : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: webUrl)

        //web1.scalesPageToFit = true
        web1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        web1.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        web1.loadRequest(webRequest)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According Apple Documentation

> scales​Page​To​Fit
>
> A Boolean value determining whether the webpage scales to fit the view
>   and the user can change the scale.

if `web1.scalesPageToFit` is `true` then the web content will fit in your `UIWebView` frame and the `contentSize` will have the same height and width as your `UIWebView`frame making imposible to be scrollable

so remove this line and must work

```
web1.scalesPageToFit = true
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Tried that ... doesn't work still. is it so that it won't work on a simulator ? I am using builtin simulators for testing. I don't have a device yet.

Comment: I will test and research further as soon as i can, and i will update my answer